# First 5 Elements of Array Contain Strange Values

Tags: c++

I am running into a strange issue when attempting to create a grid of a specified number of nodes, in the case of this example the grid is 5x5. The issue arises after Initialization, when I print out each node to verify that they were initialized correctly.

**Creating the grid:**

```
Node** nodes = new Node*[WIDTH];
```

**The initialization process:**

```
int getArrayIndex(int row, int col) { return (WIDTH * row) + col; };

void initializeNodes(Node** nodes) {                                                                                                                                                               

     int count = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                 

     for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row ++) {                                                                                                                                                       
         for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col ++) {                                                                                                                                                   

             count ++;                                                                                                                                                                              

             nodes[getArrayIndex(row, col)] = new Node();                                                                                                                                           
             nodes[getArrayIndex(row, col)]->num = count;                                                                                                                                           
             nodes[getArrayIndex(row, col)]->temp = INITIAL_TEMP; // 20                                                                                                                                 

         }                                                                                                                                                                                          
     }                                                                                                                                                                                              

     int middleRow = WIDTH / 2;                                                                                                                                                                     
     int middleCol = WIDTH / 2;                                                                                                                                                                     

     int quarterRow = WIDTH / 4;                                                                                                                                                                    
     int quarterCol = WIDTH / 4;                                                                                                                                                                    

     nodes[getArrayIndex(middleRow, middleCol)]->temp = 40;                                                                                                                                         
     nodes[getArrayIndex(quarterRow, quarterCol)]->temp = 0;                                                                                                                                        

     nodes[getArrayIndex(WIDTH - 3, WIDTH - 3)]->temp = 0;                                                                                                                                          

 }
```

**The printing process:**

```
void printNodes(Node** nodes) {

    for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row ++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col ++) {

            std::cout << nodes[getArrayIndex(row, col)]->toString() << std::endl;

        }
    }

}
```

**The output:**

```
num: 7381248, temp: 0
num: 7381376, temp: 0
num: 7381504, temp: 0
num: 7381632, temp: 0
num: 7381760, temp: 0
num: 6, temp: 20
num: 7, temp: 20
num: 8, temp: 20
num: 9, temp: 20
num: 10, temp: 20
num: 11, temp: 20
num: 12, temp: 20
num: 13, temp: 20
num: 14, temp: 20
num: 15, temp: 20
num: 16, temp: 20
num: 17, temp: 20
num: 18, temp: 20
num: 19, temp: 20
num: 20, temp: 20
num: 21, temp: 20
num: 22, temp: 20
num: 23, temp: 20
num: 24, temp: 20
num: 25, temp: 20
```

**Why are the first 5 nodes printing out weird values?**

- When I print the nodes during the initialization process they all appear fine. When I print them afterwards, from a different method and cpp file they appear as they do above.

Comment: You might be accessing out of bounds of your array, or accessing through uninitialized pointers. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "from a different method and cpp file they appear as they do above" -- what is that code? If I had to guess, you're assigning something uninitialized to that array. If you're on Linux, have you run the program through valgrind?

Comment: I don't really get it. You only allocate a grid with `WIDTH` nodes, but access it with rows and columns? That can only be good for the first row. Did you mean to allocate `WIDTH*WIDTH` elements?

Comment: @leemes Nailed it. Thank you for the extra set of eyes.

Comment: If you're going to be using `row x col`  emulation in a single dimension, the array should be *single* dimension and allocated as `row x col` elements sequentially. This looks like you started out wanting to do pointer-array 2D emulation via a pointer-array, then changed your mind halfway through coding it.

Comment: really *anytime* you see behavior like this, you should suspect out of bound access somewhere. it will serve you better to learn to use a memory profiler tool than to make posts on SO.

Comment: @BradAllred Thank you, I will keep that in mind. I'm just beginning to get used to C++ and the use of Valgrind.

Comment: @merb Valgrind is an excellent tool, you will learn to love it :) keep up the learning.

Comment: @merb so you really did want `WIDTH*WIDTH` *pointers*, each of which must be dynamically allocated,  rather than `WIDTH*WIDTH` *nodes* ? I only ask because it seems odd to do so. If you were trying to do 2D emulation via pointer-array, I would have expected `WIDTH` pointers, each of which points to `WIDTH` sequential nodes. Or a single `WIDTH*WIDTH` sequence of `Node`, always indexed via your `getArrayIndex()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in initializing the array of nodes using the following code:

```
Node** nodes = new Node*[WIDTH];
```

This should have been:

```
Node** nodes = new Node*[WIDTH * WIDTH];
```